# Syncing the profile photo on dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke, synchronization, photo

how I can synchronize the profile photo to the same user on different dnn portals?
I created a trigger that synchronizes all the user profile, but the profile photo is not displayed, I think is a folder/file permission problem

Comment: If that is the case, can you put the profile picture in a 'more common' area that is not specific to the portal?  Where all portals can access it.  what version of DNN are you on?  I know there used to be a lot of issues with Profile Pics around the 6.x releases(especially if you upgraded instead of a fresh install).

Comment: Thanks for answer me! I am using DNN 7, DNN sets and gets automatically the profile picture, how could do that?